# 1/z on an annulus has no anti-derivative

Tags: complex-analysis

An old exam question states

> Let $0 \leq R_1 < R_2$ and consider the set $ A:=$ {$z \in \mathbb{C}: R_1 < |z| < R_2$}, along with the function $g: A \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given as $g(z) = {1 \over z}$, $\forall z \in A$.  Show that, even though $g$ is analytic in $A$, there is no analytic function $h$ in $A$ such that $h' = g$.

By contradiction, suppose such an $h$ exists.  Naively, I'd assume it's a branch of log($z$).  Is the only issue, then, that $h$ may not be well defined, since part of the real axis is included in $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can locally define an antiderivative; the problem is continuity about the circle.

Recall for all $r$, $$\int_{C_r(0)} \frac 1z = 2 \pi i$$
So for $\frac 1z$ has no antiderivative on the annulus satisfying the fundamental theorem of calculus.

On each simply connected region we can have a logarithm function, like you said, but it cannot be extended continuously; the limit of the integral around the circle does not go to $0$.

Comment: I confused myself a bit by first thinking about log($z$), so let me verify a few details:

First off, $R_1 < r < R_2$.

Assuming $h$ analytic and well defined; and parametrizing $C_r(0)$ by $\gamma(t) = re^{it}, t \in [0,2\pi]$; we have that since $\gamma(0) = \gamma(2\pi)$, then $h(\gamma(0)) = h(\gamma(2\pi))$. However, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $$\int_{C_r(0)} {1\over z} = h(\gamma(2\pi)) - h(\gamma(0)) = 0;$$ hence contradiction.

And we need only to look at a single circle to gain this conclusion.  Limits aren't helpful since the annulus is fixed, so $r$ is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

***Hint:*** if $r<k<R$ show the integral of $g(z)=1/z$ around the circle $|z|=r$ is not $0$. Then if $h'(z)=g(z)$ what happens when say you first integrate $g$ over the top of the circle, then the bottom, using that the integral of $g$ over the top for example is obtained by plugging in the endpoints into $h$ and subtracting.